# Percentage MySQL Queries for Google Chart with filter options

Tags: mysql, google-visualization

I have a query that returns the percentage I need, at an overall level:

```
SELECT
    CAST(((count(LOWER(`q3`)='no')/(select count(`q3`) from `data`))*100) as decimal (10,2))
FROM `data`
WHERE LOWER(`q3`)='no'
```

This will return the percentage who said `no` in column `q3` and is accurate (validating against running the figures in Excel) (q3 contains Yes or No for every record).

However, I want to display this data in a google chart by month and location, so I built the query up a bit:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y') AS 'Month',
    CAST(((count(LOWER(`q3`)='no')/(select count(`q3`) from `data`))*100) as decimal (10,2)) AS 'MSO'
FROM `data` 
WHERE LOWER(`q3`)='no' AND store_list IN (5902) 
GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC
```

And these figures and not correct, taking the location out (this part will be substituted in the final website displaying the chart so it being an IN with one number I appreciate looks wrong, but could be multiple down the line) still gives me wrong figures total by month, taking the month stuff out gives me a wrong total for location (and so naturally, having them both in the above, doesn't work at all).

Been stroking the beard on this one but not sure where I'm going wrong, basically need the output to be in a google chart format of:

[google chart layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVBPn.png)

But I'm getting figures of May-19 1.69, Jun-19 0.56 & Jul-19 6.18 = (

Comment: you're not limiting to month, here --> `select count('q3') from 'data'`

Comment: hmm, my understanding was the grouping by year/month would do that, I'll look into that - cheers

Comment: no, because you're performing a separate select statement there, which probably isn't needed, you could possibly get by with just --> `count(`q3`)`

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat Without the separate select though I just get 100 for each month - I've tried removing the `WHERE LOWER(`q3`)='no'` leaving just the store filter in and still get 100's
[screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/oFuylDu.png)

Comment: Hmm, going back a few steps, it looks like my counts aren't working - [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/iAS1NoU.png) - the MSO is actually the total (what Q3 should be) which is doubling up. Back to stroking the beard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @WhiteHat above for talking me through this, my Counts weren't working (could be a MariaDB thing, I tried them in a MySQL format I'd googled but that didn't work) so as an alternative a count of a case seemed to do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y') AS 'Month',
    CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*))*100) as decimal (10,2)) AS 'MSO'
FROM `data` 
WHERE store_list IN (5902) 
GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC
```

If anyone comes across this on google, it's how I resolved it, thanks for talking it through with me!